# How can I remote control mac from a linux machine?

Tags: linux, mac, remote

I have a Mac Mini without a display and I'd like to remote control it, including desktop sharing, from a Linux machine.

My goal is to use XCode on the Mac Mini for iOS development.

What are my options besides VNC ?

Comment: Is VNC off the table for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [TeamViewer for Mac](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mac.aspx) and of course for Windows/Linux/Mobile.

You can consider [log-me-in](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/products/) for an alternative.

And, if you're able to run Google Chrome browser on both, there is also a share-desktop plugin in beta tests available right now.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by remote control? If you just want to launch applications and see the ouput on your linux mchine use ssh:

```
$ ssh -Y user@mac.local
```

The -Y option enables X forwarding. Any GUI application launched from the ssh session will run on the mac but be displayed on your local screen. From the ssh man page:

```
-Y       Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
         subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for desktop sharing. While your answer is correct in some type of "sharing" it doesn't do what the question asked - a GUI share.

Comment: @RichHomolka For the stated goal of using "XCode on the Mac Mini for iOS development" ssh -Y works fine. No desktop sharing, granted, but since vnc was out I thought a simple solution might be enough :).

Comment: @terdon - Xcode is a GUI application - how do you run that via ssh?

Comment: @Mark - By using the Y option as suggested by my answer.

Comment: @terdon to add to the scroll :) this looks like X11, I think XCode is a standard app, not X11. Have you tested this to see if it works?